# PHP Regex / delimiter

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have a string `"/test:n(0-2)/div/"` which I want to split via Regex into an array with function `preg_split()`. The output should be like this:

```
output = {
[0]=>"test:n(0-2)"
[1]=>"div"
}
```

However it seems not to be that easy as I have thought it is. Here are my attempts: https://regex101.com/r/iP2lD8/1

```
$re = '/\/.*\//';
$str = '/test:n(0-2)/div/';
$subst = '';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```

> Full match 0-17:
>   /test:n(0-2)/div/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `explode()`:

```
$result = array_filter(explode('/', $string));
```

`array_filter()` removes the empties from the `/` on either end.  Alternately you could `trim()` it:

```
$result = explode('/', trim($string, '/'));
```

But to answer the question, you would just use `/` as the pattern for `preg_split()` and either escape the `/` as in `/\//` or use different delimiters:

```
$result = array_filter(preg_split('#/#', $string));
```

Another way depending on your needs and complexity of the string contents:

```
preg_match_all('#/([^/]+)#', $string, $result);
print_r($result[1]);
```

`$result[0]` is an array of full matches and `$result[1]` is an array of the first capture group `()`. If there were more capture groups you would have more array elements in `$result`.

Comment: Not working, the outcome for this is: Array
(
    [1] => table
    [2] => tr:n(1-2)
)

Comment: Same issue for the second option :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
'~/([^/]+)~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nV6eC7/1). This pattern matches a `/` and then captures into   Group 1 1 or more characters other than `/`.

The issue you had is that the trailing slash was consumed. Also, you used greedy matching, that just grabbed too much.

[Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/rj8etS):

```
$re = '~/([^/]+)~'; 
$str = "/test:n(0-2)/div/"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
// => Array  ( [0] => test:n(0-2) [1] => div  )
```

Comment: Why is it saved into $matches[1]? I would have expected to have the first occurence in $matches[0] and the second one in $matches[1]

Comment: That depends on how many parts you have. Is it always just 2? Then [`'~/([^/]+)/([^/]+)~'`](https://regex101.com/r/nV6eC7/2) can help. See [**this demo**](http://ideone.com/oDMipZ).